# How to set composer flag --no-dev for Amazon AWS deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, composer-php, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy my Symfony 3 app on Amazon AWS Elastic beanstalk. I'm creating a folder `ebextentions` in root dir. In this dir I'm add a `composer.config` file which contains such code:

```
options_settings:
    aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini:
        composer_options: --no-dev
```

but it doesn't work for me. 
So, what config and where should I make for deploy project without developer requirements?

Comment: is the folder in the root dir `.ebextensions` (hidden folder starting with a dot)?

Answer (score 1):

I just run into this same issue..

checking the eb-activity.log the --no-dev argument wasn't getting passed.

**Here's what worked for me:**

```
option_settings:
  - namespace:  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini
    option_name: composer_options
    value: --no-dev
```

*The Amazon documentation seems misleading / incorrect..*
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.container.html#php-namespaces

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you did put the config file in `.ebextensions` instead of `ebextensions`, the real issue is that the `options_settings` key is a misspelling. It should actually be `option_settings`:

```
option_settings:
    aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini:
        composer_options: --no-dev
```

Here's the relevant [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.container.html#php-namespaces) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your folder name is wrong. You are using `ebextentions` when the file should be named `.ebextentions` (there is a dot at the beginning).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46185063/255260) for a full example.