# Composer install on AWS without development requirements

Tags: amazon-web-services, composer-php, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is there some way how to override AWS Elastic BeanStalk default composer install command?

I want to run `composer install --no-dev`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can append extra flags to the composer command in AWS Beanstalk.

You need to create an extra config file in `<app-root-dir>/.ebextensions/composer.config`:

```yaml
commands:
  10updateComposer:
    command: export COMPOSER_HOME=/root && /usr/bin/composer.phar self-update
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    option_name: COMPOSER_HOME
    value: /root
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini:
    composer_options: --no-dev
```

Whatever you put in `composer_options` will be appended to the composer command line.

You can verify this is executed correctly by looking at your `/var/log/eb-activity.log` file. Look out for something like this:

```
 ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config optionsettings -n aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini -o composer_options
  + PHP_COMPOSER_OPTIONS=--no-dev
  + echo 'Found composer.json file. Attempting to install vendors.'
  Found composer.json file. Attempting to install vendors.
  + composer.phar install --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-dev
```

For more info you can read the [Composer File](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.container.html#php-configuration-composer) section in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

What's above and in the official EBS documentation didn't work when I tried..

**Here's what worked for me:**

```
option_settings:
  - namespace:  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini
    option_name: composer_options
    value: --no-dev
```

*Not sure if theres an error in the documentation at this link but I submitted a report on it..*
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.container.html#php-namespaces